# removing towel rack

Tags: brackets

I have a bath towel rack in our bathroom and one of the bar holders has stripped out of the wall. My plan was to try to reattach it, but I cannot figure out how the hardware works.

Here's a picture of the other bar holder that is still in the wall.  There are no set screws or anything on the outside of the holder:
[image]

Here's a picture of the side that has pulled off:
[image]

Here are the holes:
[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this.  It looks like there is no way to mount anything on the wall, since the bracket is attached to the towel holder.  I guess I could try to replace the whole thing, but I am unsure how to get the other side out other than just pulling on it, and I'm afraid I might tear up the drywall if I do that.  Anybody ever seen this type of hardware before on a towel rack and any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Is there a set screw in from one side of the towel bar pedestal?

Comment: @Michael Karas - No, there are no set screws

Answer (score 1):

The holder snaps into the part attached to the wall anchor in your photo.

You want to pull or push on the springs (i.e. the clip you have labelled) and release the bracket from the rod holder.

Then re-attach the bracket to the wall.

Then the rod holder pushes onto the bracket until it latches.

Comment: Presumably to remove the other one (nicely) you would slip something in to hook that spring clip and release it. With any luck the designer will spend eternity in an uncomfortable location for such a clever "only see how it works after you yank it off the wall" design.

Comment: These come with a "tool" that can slip behind and release the latch but I'm sure that's long gone.  You might be able to do it with a paint scraper or a credit card.  With stuff like this it's definitely form over function!

Comment: Even the first owner rarely keeps track of that stuff, and if they do, some genius will throw it all away when the house is sold...making it a bad design for real life.

Comment: @jwh20 - Thanks for the suggestion on the credit card, but unfortunately I think the clip is too far back for the card to reach it (I did try it, but no luck).

Comment: @Ecnerwal - LOL, I agree with you about the design :).  Maybe I can work the other side out gently a little ways and then try the credit card thing.  I'm just terrified of cracking the drywall and creating a bigger issue.